# Long varchar into varchar Ingres DB

Tags: sql, varchar, ingres

I have INGRES DB 10.0

I have variable with LONG VARCHSR  data type. in which users submit long string, 
then i have while loop which taking +2000 characters from this string and put it in table where column has varchar (255) data type. when i am trying to compile this procedure i getting error `E_US0971 Target list expression of type 'long varchar' cannot be coerced into local variable/parameter of type 'varchar'`

here is my  while loop

```
    :notelinenumber = 1; 
    :i = 1;

WHILE :i < LENGTH(:note_text)
    do 
    select SUBSTRING (:note_text, :i, 1900) into :note_part;

    INSERT INTO NOTE
            (note_number,
             note_line_number,
             note_date_stamp,
             note_text)
    VALUES  ( :note_number,
              :notelinenumber,
              Date( 'now' ),
              :note_part); 

        :i = :i+1900;
        :notelinenumber = :notelinenumber+1;        
ENDWHILE;
```

here is `:note_text` = long varchar data type  but `note_part` =  varchar (255).

How i can convert  that  part  which i receiving from my while loop from long varchar into varchar (255)?

Comment: @dazedandconfused varchar (255) can hold up to 2000 characters. stop confusing me

Answer (score -2):

Answer was so easy just simply have to convert long varchar into varchar

```
    :notelinenumber = 1; 
    :i = 1;

WHILE :i < LENGTH(:note_text)
    do 
    select varchar( SUBSTRING (:note_text, :i, 1900)) into :note_part;

    INSERT INTO NOTE
            (note_number,
             note_line_number,
             note_date_stamp,
             note_text)
    VALUES  ( :note_number,
              :notelinenumber,
              Date( 'now' ),
              :note_part); 

        :i = :i+1900;
        :notelinenumber = :notelinenumber+1;        
ENDWHILE;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think varchar(255) can hold 2000 characters? Perhaps check out the behaviour of "SELECT cast('123456789' AS varchar(5))", which should give you a flavour of what I expect is happening. Even after you have successfully cast the long varchar as a varchar, you will still suffer from unintentional trimming. You will need to increase the size of your note_text varchar or reduce the length of string you are putting in :note_part.

Comment: @littlefeltfangs i am  splitting text  from longvarchar  into varchar  by  1900 characters. example if long varchar  holds 2000 characters after it will go troughs this while statement I will have in 2 records in the table,  First will contain 1900 characters and have note_number 1 and note_line_number 1, second record will have 100 characters and will have not_number 1 and note_line_number= 2 . so my code perfectly works for my needs